# PHP - Dynamically change variable

Tags: php, html, css

My website runs on a single page with dynamic CSS changes. If I want to direct the client to a page content, all I do is giving the page link with passing CSS id. i.e: *www.ilstours.net/index.php?css=1*

index.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/<?php echo $css; ?>.php" />
    </head>
    <body>
<button id="button1" type="button" onclick="index.php?css=2">Update</button> 'HERE
    </body>
    </html>
```

1.php:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$Color = "black";
?>
body {background-color:<?php echo $Color ?>;}
```

2.php:

```
  <?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    $Color = "red";
    ?>
    body {background-color:<?php echo $Color ?>;}
```

How can I switch to CSS file 2.php upon button click?

Comment: What is the issue with the current code ? You want your url to be change on each click ?

Comment: `onclick="index.php?css=2"` This is not a valid attribute value. I want to manipulate variable within a php.

Comment: @Litestone have you check my answer?

Comment: I suggest you to use `jQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**index.php**

```
<?php
$css = 1; // default css (1)
if(isset($_REQUEST['css']) && ($_REQUEST['css']==1 || $_REQUEST['css']==2))
{
  $css = $_REQUEST['css']; // update by click on button (1 or 2)
}

?>
      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/<?php echo $css; ?>.php" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <button id="button1" type="button" onclick="location.href='index.php?css=1';">Update CSS 1</button>
            <button id="button1" type="button" onclick="location.href='index.php?css=2';">Update CSS 2</button>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You wrote $_REQEUST instead of $_REQUEST

Answer (score 0):

As you pass the value by url, use $_GET to access it

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/<?php echo $_GET['css']; ?>.php" />
```

Comment: I didn't think to GET variable. It's a good idea. But it is not working dynamically, still.

Comment: You also need 'location.href' in your onclick attribute. I think @Satish Sharma answer is a what you need

Comment: It is working with  $_REQUEST['css'] rather than  $_GET['css']. What is the difference?

Comment: In general, `$_REQUEST` contains the contents of `$_GET` or `$_POST`. You use `$_GET` when you request data from url. In your case, `$_GET` should work. Try using @SatishSharma code with `$_GET`.

Comment: His code was working fine at first look, however, it destroys all transition effects like duration because of `location.href` which is acting like navigating to a different link. I am still in looking for alternative ways.

Comment: Do you need to change only the body background?

Comment: No, every styling php will include many styles according to navigation. If the client navigates to my radio channel, the page will display radio divs, pics, etc... If navigates to TV, the page will turn into a tv channel. My only aim is not the refresh the page and provide a smooth experience.

Comment: So, I suggest you to use jquery. Here is a tuto for switching css with  jquery http://www.jquery4u.com/dynamic-css-2/jquery-change-css-file-2/

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['css'])) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/'.$_GET['css'].'.php" />';

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Better keep your css in single array like

```
<?php
   $my_css = array("1"=>"1.css","2"=>"2.css",'deflt' => 'defualt.css');
?>
```

and include css like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/<?php echo (isset($_GET['css']) && isset($my_css[$_GET['css']])) ? $my_css[$_GET['css']] : 'defualt.css'; ?>" />
```

Comment: if url is `index.php?css=abcd` which css will be load